# Google chrome failed to parse extension manifest

Tags: google-chrome, debian

After upgrading Google chrome from 34 version to 35 it doesn't work.
I use debian testing. As soon as I run

> google-chrome

from console I get an error:
"Error...: failed to parse extension manifest" after that I get login screen.
I've tried to reinstall the browser, cleaned chrome's cache and config folders. But result the same.
Also I can't get detail log. I tried to run google chrome from console like:

```
google-chrome > log.txt
```

but I got empty log.txt file.

Also I checked /var/log/... files. But I didn't find anything interesting.
It would be great if someone tells me how I can get detailed log information or how to fix this issue:)

Answer (score 0):

Try

chrome 2> log.txt

Same here. But I not even get to any screen. Crashes right away after an update (there was a new Chromium AND also kernel update coming following each other a few days apart. Because I didn't start Chromium in between I cannot even tell what could cause this.

I also assume that ""Error...: failed to parse extension manifest"" here is a side effect of something more severe. I get more errors like:

ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[7351:7351:0614/212426:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(297)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process